# How to make reactor.cache.CacheMono not to call calculation twice?

Tags: spring, caching, spock, project-reactor, reactor

I'm trying to implement caching mechanism for my settings and I can't really make it working.

I have realization of my repository like this:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CachedSettingsRepository<E extends SettingsEntity> implements SettingsRepository<E> {

    private final String key;
    private final SettingsRepository<E> settingsRepository;
    private final Cache<String, Signal<? extends E>> cache;

    @Trace
    @Override
    public Mono<E> get() {
        return CacheMono.lookup(cache.asMap(), key)
                        .onCacheMissResume(settingsRepository::get);

    }

    @Trace
    @Override
    public Mono<Void> delete() {
        return settingsRepository.delete()
                                 .doOnNext(empty -> cache.invalidate(key));
    }

    @Trace
    @Override
    public Mono<E> cas(Function<Mono<E>, Publisher<E>> function) {
        return settingsRepository.cas(function)
                                 .doOnNext(result -> cache.invalidate(key));
    }

}
```

I've configured it like this:

```
@Configuration
public class CacheContext {

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("settings.cache")
    public CacheSettingsBean paymentCacheSettingsBean() {
        return new CacheSettingsBean();
    }

    @Bean
    public Cache<String, Signal<? extends PaymentSettingsEntity>> paymentSettingsCache() {
        return Caffeine.newBuilder()
                       .maximumSize(paymentCacheSettingsBean().getMaximumSize())
                       .expireAfterWrite(paymentCacheSettingsBean().getExpireAfterWrite())
                       .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public CachedSettingsRepository<PaymentSettingsEntity> cachedPaymentSettingsRepository(
            SettingsRepository<PaymentSettingsEntity> paymentSettingsRepository,
            Cache<String, Signal<? extends PaymentSettingsEntity>> paymentSettingsCache) {
        return new CachedSettingsRepository<>(paymentCacheSettingsBean().getKey(), paymentSettingsRepository, paymentSettingsCache);
    }

}
```

And I'm trying to test it:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.NONE,
        classes = [CacheContext, TestContext])
@ActiveProfiles("settings-cache")
@EnableConfigurationProperties
class CachedSettingsRepositoryTest extends Specification {

    @Autowired
    CachedSettingsRepository<PaymentSettingsEntity> cachedPaymentSettingsRepository
    @Autowired
    SettingsRepository<PaymentSettingsEntity> paymentSettingsRepository

    def "test getting from cache"() {
        given:
            def paymentSettings = paymentSettingsEntity()
        when:
            def result1 = cachedPaymentSettingsRepository.get().block()
            def result2 = cachedPaymentSettingsRepository.get().block()
        then:
            1 * paymentSettingsRepository.get() >> Mono.just(paymentSettings)
            0 * _

            result1 == paymentSettings
            result1 == result2
    }

    def paymentSettingsEntity() {
        PaymentSettingsEntity.of([PaymentRangeSetting.of(0.0, 100.0)])
    }

    @Configuration
    static class TestContext {
        private DetachedMockFactory factory = new DetachedMockFactory()

        @Bean
        SettingsRepository<PaymentSettingsEntity> paymentSettingsRepository() {
            factory.Mock(SettingsRepository)
        }
    }

}
```

I expect that it will call my paymentSettingsRepository on the first try and then will return cached on the second, but test is failing all the time.

Comment: I know quite something about Spock, which is why I found the question. I know next to nothing about Spring or Spring Boot, though. So, looking at the Spock documentation, I saw a test example similar to yours, but it used `@TestConfiguration` instead of just `@Configuration`. As I am currently busy and have no time to reproduce your whole situation - an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for me to clone on GitHub would be helpful - I am guessing against my habit, which is probably a bad idea. With the MCVE I could analyse instead.

Answer (score 1):

The reason of such behavior is in the CacheMono implementation and specific of the test. Here is the code of CacheMono:

```
public static <KEY, VALUE> MonoCacheBuilderMapMiss<VALUE> lookup(Map<KEY, ? super Signal<? extends VALUE>> cacheMap, KEY key) {
    return otherSupplier -> Mono.defer(() ->
            Mono.justOrEmpty(cacheMap.get(key))
                .switchIfEmpty(otherSupplier.get().materialize()
                                .doOnNext(value -> cacheMap.put(key, value)))
                .dematerialize()
    );
}
```

It uses defer call only before getting from cache but otherSupplier.get() wasn't defered, so test fails.

I suppose it would be good to change 
    `otherSupplier.get()`
to 
    `Mono.defer(() -> otherSupplier.get())`

Comment: I think that is a valid point. would you be willing to open a PR against the reactor-addons repo?

Comment: @SimonBaslé This issue still doesn't seem to be fixed, onCacheMissResume is being called every time whether or not there is value in cache, making CacheMono unusable

Comment: @SimonBaslé Added a bug at https://github.com/reactor/reactor-addons/issues/234